# Perl portable serialization only with CORE modules

Tags: perl

Exists any portable serialization method/Module what is included in the CORE modules? I know here is `Storable`, but it is not truly portable nor "cross-platform-standardized". Looking for something like YAML, JSON, XML or like...

I already chcecked the http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-T.html - but maybe missed something.

Motivation: want make a simple perl script what will works with any perl (without CPAN) and can read some configuration (and data) from a file. Using `require` with the Data::Dumper format is not very "user friendly"...

So possible solutions:

- include something like YAML directly to my script (can be a solution, but...)
- forcing users to install CPAN modules (not a solution)
- use native perl and `require` - not very userfriendly syntax (for a non-perl users)

Any other suggested solution?

Ps: Understand the need keep core as small as possible and reasonable, but *reading data* in some standardized formats maybe? should be in a core...

Comment: It might help if you explained exactly *why* you can't use CPAN modules. You allude to not wanting to make users install modules; are these end users or internal users? What OSs do you have to support? There are [packaging tools](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) that can help you distribute your program along with its dependencies, but without more details, it's hard to say if that would be a viable solution for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a YAML parser and serializer bundled with Perl, hidden away. It's called `CPAN::Meta::YAML`. It only handles a subset of YAML, but that may be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Oh, how could I forget...?! JSON::PP also comes with Perl 5.13.9 and above!!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Data::Dumper's output to be JSON-like. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Pair = ': ';
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my $structure = {
    foo => 'bar',
    baz => {
        quux => 'duck',
        badger => 'mythical',
    }
};

print Dumper( $structure );
```

This prints:

```
{
  "baz": {
    "quux": "duck",
    "badger": "mythical"
  },
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

That might get you most of the way towards interoperability? The module does have a bunch of options for controlling / changing output e.g. the Freezer and Toaster options.

Comment: That won't help, because we can't just `eval` that format to load the data.

Comment: How does it help to make the output like JSON if you can't read it as JSON?

Comment: Looks valid JSON to me, and to http://jsonlint.com/. Granted, it lacks the usual "$VAR1 = " preamble that Data::Dumper adds and makes it easier to eval in Perl, but if that were a problem then the Perl code could add it back in?

Comment: @RoryHunter The issue is the `:` separator which would sabotage an `eval` (This simply isn't Perl code), and the incompatible string encoding – try to put the non-ascii `×` in there – it should be encoded as `\u00D7`, it will be encoded as `\x{d7}` which isn't JSON. The result is a Franken-format that's neither Perl nor JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain to me the problem with [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) again? If you look at [Perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html), after a discussion of Bigendiness and Littleendiness, it concludes:

> One can circumnavigate both these problems in two ways. Either transfer and store numbers always in text format, instead of raw binary, or else consider using modules like **Data::Dumper** and **Storable** (included as of perl 5.8). Keeping all data as text significantly simplifies matters.

So, Storable is universal for storing and retrieving data in Perl, and it's not only easy to use, but it's a standard Perl module.

Is the issue that you want to be able to write the data without having a Perl program do it for you? You could simply write your own Perl module. In most Perl installations, that module could be placed in the same directory as your program.

```
package Some_data;   # Can be put in the same directory as the program like a config file

our $data;           # Module variable which makes it accessible to your local program
$data = {};          # I am making this complex data structure...

$data->{NAME}->{FIRST}          = "Bob";
$data->{NAME}->{LAST}           = "Smith";
$data->{PHONE}->[0]->{TYPE}     = "C";
$data->{PHONE}->[0]->{NUMBER}   = "555-1234";
$data->{PHONE}->[1]->{TYPE}     = "H";
$data->{PHONE}->[1]->{NUMBER}   = "555-2345";

# Or use Subroutines

sub first {
    return "Bob";
}

sub last {
    return "Smith"
}

...
```

Now you can include this in your program:

```
use Some_data;

my $first_name = $Some_data::data->{NAME}->{FIRST}  # As a hash of hashes

# OR

my $first_name = Some_data::first;                  # As a constant
```

The nice thing about the subroutines is that you can't change the data in your program. They're constants. In fact, that's exactly how Perl constants work too.

Speaking about constants. You could use `use constant` too:

```
package Some_data;

use constant {
    FIRST => "Bob",
    SECOND => "Smith",
};
```

And in your program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Some_data;

my $fist_name = &Some_Data::FIRST;  # Note the use of the ampersand!
```

Not quite as clean because you need to prefix the constant with an ampersand. There are ways of getting around that ampersand, but they're not all that pretty.

Now, you have a way of importing your data in your program, and it's really no harder to maintain than a JSON data structure. There's nothing your program has to do except to `use Module;` to get that data.

---

### One final possibility

Here's one I've done before. I simply have a configuration file that looks like what you'd put on the command line, then use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) to pull in the configuration:

#### Configfile

```
-first Bob -last Smith
-phone 555-1212
```

> **NOTE**: It doesn't matter if you put it all on one line or not:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
 use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptionsFromString);

open my $param_fh, "<", $param_file;
my @parameters = <$param_fh>;
close $param_fh;
my $params = join " ", $parameters   # One long string
my ( $first, $phone );
GetOptionsFromString ( $params,
    "first=s"   => \$first,
    "phone=s"   => \$phone,
);
```

You can't get easier to maintain than that!

Comment: It's not exactly clear from the question, but it seems like the OP wants *users* to be able to write the config files. Hence the desire to avoid Data::Dumper: requiring non-programmers to write config files using Perl syntax is less than ideal.

Comment: A module may be the easiest way for users to configure their own data. You give them the basic structure, and it's a lot easier to maintain than a JSON file. After all, if you're a Perl developer, it's just Perl. There's one more possibility and that's using Getopt::Long to read in a configuration file much the same way you'd read in parameters passed from a program. Maybe I'll append that to my answer.